# String matching plus Boolean value reassignment in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to find all the value, which is a more complex query than I'm used to. I'll be changing the values of millions of values potentially, so the most efficient way to find rows, which meet these conditions, and how to change their values would be really helpful.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

example = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['9+'],
                        'b': [False]})

# If example['a'] contains a '9' or a '10' AND example['b'] is 'False' then change example['a'] to '8'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use [Pandas boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
In [126]: example
Out[126]:
     a      b
0   9+  False
1  10-  False
2    9   True
3    1   True
4    2  False

In [127]: example.loc[example['a'].str.contains('9|10') & ~example['b'], 'a'] = '8'

In [128]: example
Out[128]:
   a      b
0  8  False
1  8  False
2  9   True
3  1   True
4  2  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use `df.apply()` ?

```
def get_new_a(x):
    if ('9' in x.a or '10' in x.a) and x.b == False:
        return '8'
    else:
        return x.a

example['a_2'] = example.apply(get_new_a, axis=1)
```

So your dataframe becomes:

```
    a      b   a_2
 0  9+  False   8
```